# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my query?

Tags: sql, count

```
SELECT 
    T1.Description, T1.TYPE, T1.SALESPOTENTIAL , T2.STARTDATE,  
    T3.PROJECT_REGION, T3.JOB_TYPE
FROM 
    sysdba.OPPORTUNITY T1,
    SELECT T1.TYPE, count(*)
    FROM OPPORTUNITY
    GROUP BY by TYPE,
JOIN 
    sysdba.ACTIVITY T2 ON T1.ACCOUNTID = T2.ACCOUNTID
JOIN 
    sysdba.C_OPPORTUNITY_EXT T3 ON T1.OPPORTUNITYID = T3.OPPORTUNITYID
WHERE 
    CLOSEPROBABILITY > 70
```

Comment: one thing wrong with it is formatting

Comment: you are using two select queries as a single query?

Comment: can you show us the error message when you execute that query.

Comment: Please add related tables, sample data and required output.

Comment: And add the db engine you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The line "GROUP BY by TYPE," has bad syntax.

Use only one BY.
TYPE is a reserved word. If this refers to a field, then use `TYPE` (surround the field name with the ` character).
The comma at the end shouldn't be there.

```
GROUP BY `TYPE`
```

If using Mysql, it's also good practice to put sub-queries inside parentesis. This becomes a "derived table" and needs a name. I've used "someTempTable" in this example:

```
(SELECT T1.TYPE, count(*)
    FROM OPPORTUNITY
    GROUP BY `TYPE`) as someTempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a naked select statement in the from part. On some (all?) databases, you can, however, go like so:

```
select
   col1,
   col2
from
   table_1                                    join
  (select ... from inner_table) table_2 on table_1.x = table_2.y;
```

Note the paranthesis around the select statement.